# How to make the session cookie secure with Seedstack?

Tags: seedstack

I'm using Web sessions in a SeedStack application but needs the session cookie to be secured by the httpOnly flag.

Since there is no configuration option for that, how can I achieve this with the current version ?

Comment: Thanks for your question. It has been closed but I requested it to be re-opened.

Comment: It's been reopened apparently, if you have any hint on how to do this @AdrienLAUER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for now to configure the session cookie used by Undertow but I added the relevant options to make it possible in the upcoming version (20.4 at the end of April).

For now, as a workaround, you can implement a [ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) to configure the session cookie manually:

```
public class MyServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> classes, ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
    }
```

Your class must be registered in a `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file:

```
org.myorg.myproject.MyServletContainerInitializer
```

Note that you can statically obtain a configuration facade with `Seed.baseConfiguration()`. This makes it possible to alter cookie options using applicative configuration.